# Free tools to test Web Service traffic?

Tags: c#, web-services, statistics, traffic

I wrote a web service in C#. Now, i need to test the web service traffic to get information like (how long does it take to get response, how many responses can be handled in an hour etc. pretty much statistics about the web service). Is there any tools (free/paid) to get this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are variety of load testing tools if that is what you are looking for. I'm not sure how well they work on custom web services or how to implement them but you could start with soapUI (http://www.soapui.org/About-SoapUI/what-is-soapui.html) or WCAT(http://www.iis.net/community/default.aspx?tabid=34&i=1466&g=6) the latter of which is typically for IIS. I have no idea how you built your webservice though so its just a suggestion

Answer (score 4):

[Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) can help you with that.

You can measure it for one client this way.  However, if you need broader information for all users at once, you will need something different.

Answer (score 2):

If your services use WCF techology, you can use [WCF performance counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735098.aspx).
Enable them using this configuration:

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <diagnostics performanceCounters="All" />
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

It includes pretty much everything you need.